# Get next tick within Vue3 setup script

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How do you use the next tick within the setup script in vue3?

```
<script setup>


const msg = 'Hello!'

this.$nextTick(() => {
   console.log("next tick ... do something")
});

</script>

<template>
  <p>{{ msg }}</p>
</template>
```

I've used multiple different methods but I can't find one that works outside of the normal script tags.

Another method I tried was.

```
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.nextTick(() => {});
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is how you can use `nextTick()` in Vue 3.

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, nextTick } from 'vue'

const count = ref(0)

async function increment() {
  count.value++

  // DOM not yet updated
  console.log(document.getElementById('counter').textContent) // 0

  await nextTick()
  // DOM is now updated
  console.log(document.getElementById('counter').textContent) // 1
}
</script>

<template>
  <button id="counter" @click="increment">{{ count }}</button>
</template>
```

Here you can find more informations: https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick

Answer (score 8):

While the answer from [Mises](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6310260/mises) is correct, nextTick() can also be used without async/await as follows:

```
nextTick().then(() => {
    // DOM is now updated
    console.log("Continue here")
}
```

I would consider this slightly more best practice, as it allows you to work with Promises.